# How do you send a "tap" to an apple watch programmatically

Tags: ios, watchkit

I have a project in mind where I would have to be able to send a tap/haptic feedback/vibration to an Apple Watch. Is this possible with Watchkit? If so, how can I accomplish it. (preferably objective-c).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no method in WatchKit to play a sound or trigger Taptic feedback. The closest you can get is to send a `UILocalNotification`, but even then, you can't control where that notification is displayed, as iOS decides whether to send it to the iPhone or the Watch. Hopefully this will be added in a future update.